# Robust real-time communication between iOS App and Mac App

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, ipad, sockets

We're working on an exhibit (http://pulse.media.mit.edu) and I'm brand new to iOS, objective-c and Xcode.  The exhibit deadline is in one week and I'm stuck.

The problem I'm having seemed simple enough.

Our exhibit has a projector and an iPad.  The projector will be hooked up to a mac and be playing a video.  The iPad will act as a controller for those videos.  More simply:

I have 50 videos on a Mac.  I need to develop an application on the Mac, that, when opened will loop one of the videos.

On an iPad, I need to develop an app that can change between the videos on the mac in real time.  The iOS app is already designed, we're just struggling with some code.

On the mac, when the iPad tells the Mac to change video, we'd like it to switch between videos using Core Animation, like this (http://youtu.be/pyd8O-2mkgk?t=1m).

So my question: What is the most robust way to do this?  It has to be able to run in a museum, for two months.  Some things to consider:

- We are 4,000 miles away and can't monitor it all the time.  We'll
  check nightly to see if it's still working, but it should run the day
  without breaking.
- If people unplug the iPad, it should still work.
- It should be as robust as possible.

**How can I best do this?  Should I write to a database from the iPad onto a database running locally on the connected Mac and then monitor that database 10 times every second?  Are sockets robust enough to use alone?**

If you do suggest a way, can you please point me in the direction of some resources (frameworks, function names, etc) that can help me do this quickly?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It probably depends a lot on which program you are playing the videos with.  If the video player program responds to AppleScript commands, then I would start by figuring out how to write an AppleScript that controls the video player when you run it on the Mac.  Once that's working, the next step would be to figure out how to invoke that script from the iPad... perhaps via ssh or rsh.

Comment: When you say "Nothing relevant"... What *have* you found? How has it been unhelpful?

Comment: I guess I'm most interested in strategy here.  I'm not sure what will be reliable.  This is for an exhibit 2000 miles away from my house.  And although I can remote in, I can't constantly check to see if it's down.  I'm looking for someone to say "this method is the most reliable real time communication between the iPad and computer.  use wifi because xyz.  Here's some key areas to look at.  QTKit for controlling the video.  [insert framework] for realtime communication, etc.  I can piece it together after that.  But for now, I have no real leads.

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388739/whats-the-most-simple-way-to-bi-directional-communication-between-ios-and-mac-os ?

Comment: I have now.  So how would that work?  From the iPad, send the video id to a mysql database?  Then on the mac, just loop, constantly checking the database for changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for the server-in-the-middle option, because it will be easiest to debug, and requires nothing more than a working internet (wifi) connection on the client side. When having connection issues, all you need is someone who knows how to hook up an iPad or Mac to the internet. And you can see server-side which device has issues connecting.

Furthermore, using plain HTTP sounds like the best way to go for communication, and the backend can be written in any server side scripting language. Both clients should be polling the server every X seconds.

If you get this basic setup working well before your deadline, you could try to get the devices to connect to eachother directly (for a less sluggish user experience), and leave the server solution in there as a fallback method. The Mac app could function as a HTTP server, accepting the very same commands that the iPad normally sends to your server. The challenge will be to reliably know which IP to connect to. You could hardcode it or use Bonjour.